# Padding a number doesn't work when transferring to LaTeX

Tags: export, output-formatting, latex

I have some numbers which I calculate via some previous code. The calculation works fine. However since I want to compare it with experimental data I only need the numbers to a certain number of significant figures.

As an example I have a tuple of numbers:

```
l = {0.5567857946, 0.55670214585}
```

I then round this to 5 s.f using `SetPrecision[l, 5]` which when I print it I obtain `{0.55679, 0.55670}` which is good, but when I export it to LaTeX and compile it, it is displayed as `0.55679 0.5567`. This is not what I want. The following code is an example of what I use to export to LaTeX.

```
expdat = {
   {"\\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|}"},
   {"\\hline"},
   {"Output", "&", "$Heading1$", "&", "$Heading2$", "\\\\"},
   {"\\hline"},
   {"$l$", "&", l[[1 ]], "&", l[[2]], "\\\\"},
   {"\\hline"},
   {"\\end{tabular}"}
   };

Export["data.tex", expdat, "Table"]
```

This results in the desired LaTeX code which I can input into my document using:

```
\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em} 
\input{data}
\caption{MyCaption}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
```

Everything comes out fine except I lose the zeroes on the end of my numbers. The LaTeX code itself does not have the zeroes, so the problem lies somewhere within Mathematica/the transfer to LaTeX.

I have tried the following in Mathematica.

`PaddedForm[SetPrecision[l, 5], {5, 5}]` but this results in the LaTeX displaying where the first l value should be displaying as a pair of numbers except they are the values of l to arbitrary length. Where the second l value should be is displayed as "5,5". If I change the Mathematica code to

```
expdat = {
   {"\\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|}"},
   {"\\hline"},
   {"Output", "&", "$Heading1$", "&", "$Heading2$", "\\\\"},
   {"\\hline"},
   {"$l$", "&", l[[1 ,1]], "&", l[[1, 2]], "\\\\"},
   {"\\hline"},
   {"\\end{tabular}"}
   };

Export["data.tex", expdat, "Table"]
```

Then I get the same as I did before using PaddedForm.

I have done similar with `NumberForm[SetPrecision[l, 5], {5, 5}]` but I get the exact same problem.

Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you exactly tried. Also, your question hinges on how [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export) handles numbers, and doesn't really have anything to do with LaTeX. I think the problem is that you need to [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map) or [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread) your [`PaddedForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PaddedForm) over your list:

```
l = Thread[NumberForm[{0.5567857946, 0.55670214585}, {5, 5}], List, 1]
```

Note I used [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm) instead of [`PaddedForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PaddedForm). Then:

```
expdat = {
    {"\\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|}"},
    {"\\hline"},
    {"Output","&","$Heading1$","&","$Heading2$","\\\\"},
    {"\\hline"},{"$l$","&",l[[1]],"&",l[[2]],"\\\\"},
    {"\\hline"},{"\\end{tabular}"}
};
ExportString[expdat, "Table"]

"\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|}
\hline
Output & $Heading1$ & $Heading2$ \\
\hline
$l$ & 0.55679 & 0.55670 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}"
```

I used [`ExportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportString) so that you can see what the file would look like.